# Get one variable from JSON to Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

We've been looking for some time to fix this problem, but we're in a hurry, that's why we want to ask you. We have the following (really small) json file:

```
{"count":28}
```

How do we get '28' as a javascript int? We already know how to load the file etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. JavaScript only has a `Number` data type, it doesn't support integers as their own type.

Comment: "We already know how to load the file etc" — So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have loaded the file, you can extract the value you need:

```
var json = {"count":28};
var count = parseInt(json.count)
```

EDIT:
the documentation says you should always specify the radix as a second argument to avoid any misunderstandings:

```
var count = parseInt(json.count, 10)
```

The retrieved integer is a decimal number.

This will get you the value in `count` as an integer. You should get 28 even if the value is for example 28.5. But if you do:

```
console.log(typeof count)
```

it will return 'number'. That is because there is a primitive type 'Number' in JavaScript that doesn't make distinction between integers and floating point numbers.

Comment: parseInt will work fine, what do you mean by non support in some browsers?

Comment: in code that you provide, you not need in parseInt, because `json.count` already int

Comment: @scunliffe I was not sure if it is supported by old browsers, like IE < 8, so I thought it should be mentioned.

Comment: @Grundy yes, in this example "count" contains 28, but the OP was explcitly asking for getting an integer. What if there is `"count": "28"` or `"count": "2em"`? Then he'd like to explicitly get the integer.

Comment: @cezar it has been supported by all browsers that I'm aware of since JavaScript 1.0 (~Netscape 2 ERA) ;-)

Comment: @scunliffe, i think cezar confused it with [Number.parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt)

Comment: @scunliffe Thank you for your remark. I'll edit my post. Grundy is right, I know there were some browser issues with `parseInt`, but that is `Number.parseInt`. Thanks Grundy, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = '{"count":28}',
obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have loaded JSON content into variable:

```
var json = '{"count":28}';
```

just parse it with:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(jsonObject.count);
```